# When accessing from a computer, I got the "mobile" style view

Tags: support, mobile-web

Strangely, I only got this when accessing RPG.SE. (Nothing else, even meta.RPG.SE.)

First image:
[image]

Second image for comparison:
[image]

Any ideas?

Note: Awards, profile, and badges that have something to do with RPG.SE is in mobile view.

My clock is +7 GMT.

Comment: You misclicked "mobile" in the footer. It's "sticky"...